# Monitor connector for C64 and ST the same?

Tags: commodore-64, crt-monitor, atari-st

I have a monitor (colour) that works on my Atari ST. The connector looks similar to that of my Commodore 64, but it doesn’t seem to fit. Now I don’t know if I just have to use a bit more force, or these connectors are different. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The connectors are different, and will not fit. If you look at the ends of the connectors, you should see that the number of pins, and how they are laid out, are different. Specifically, the Commodore 64 uses an 8-pin DIN connector, and the ST uses a 13-pin DIN connector.